# PHP Insert from form

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

I am struggling with inserting some records into my DB from a table that is produced from a PHP loop.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

if($action=='removed'){
    echo "<div>" . $_GET['name'] . " was removed from cart.</div>";
}

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $ids = "";
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$id){ $ids = $ids . $id . ","; }

    // remove the last comma
    $ids = rtrim($ids, ',');

    $query = "SELECT events.*, agegroup.*, eventtypes.* FROM events  LEFT JOIN agegroup  ON events.AgeGroupID=agegroup.AgeGroupID  LEFT JOIN eventtypes  ON events.EventTypeID=eventtypes.EventTypeID WHERE events.EventID IN ({$ids})";

    $stmt = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($stmt);

    if($num>0){

        echo "<table border='0'>";//start table

            // our table heading
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Product Name</th>";
                echo "<th>Price (GBP)</th>";
                echo "<th>Action</th>";
                  echo "<th>Add Swimmer</th>";
                  echo "<th></th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            //also compute for total price
            $totalPrice = 0;

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
                extract($row);

                $totalPrice += $EventCost;

                //creating new table row per record

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<form action='cart.php' method='POST' name='addswimmerform'>";
                    echo "<td>{$EventType}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$EventCost}</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo "<a href='removeFromCart.php?id={$EventID}&name={$EventType}'>";
                            echo "Remove";
                        echo "</a>";
                    echo "</td>";
                      echo "<td>Swimmer Drop Down</td>";
                      echo "<td>
                        <input name='EventID' type='text' id='EventID' value='{$EventID}'>
                        <input name='ParentDiaryID' type='text' id='ParentDiaryID' value='{$ParentDiaryID}'>
                        <input name='UserID' type='text' id='UserID' value='{$UserID}'>
                      <input name='addswimmer' type='submit' id='addswimmer' title='Add Swimmer'>
                      <input type='hidden' name='MM_insert' value='addswimmerdetails'>
                      </td>";
                      echo "</form>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Total Price</th>";
                echo "<th>{$totalPrice}</th>";
                echo "<th></th>";
            echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br /><div><a href='#' class='customButton'>Checkout</a></div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div>No products found in your cart. :(</div>";
    }

}else{
    echo "<div>No products in cart yet.</div>";
}

?>
```

and here is my INSERT code further up the page:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "addswimmerdetails")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO eventregistrations (ParentDiaryID, EventID, SwimmerID, UserID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['$ParentDiaryID'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['$EventID'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['$SwimmerID'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['$UserID'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_otters, $otters);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $otters) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

So, the form on the page displays the correct values in the EventID and ParentDiaryID text fields on the page but when I click the button to insert the values I get a message saying ParentDiaryID cannot be empty.

If I change the form to GET instead of POST I can see the values populating in the URL so I know the form is passing them so I am assuming it is a problem with my INSERT statement but I can't figure out what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: When you try `echo $insertSQL`, are there values you expected?

Comment: Are you sure it's `$_POST['$ParentDiaryID']` and not `$_POST['ParentDiaryID']` without the `$`?

Comment: Oh my god I can be so stupid sometimes.  Yes I removed the $ so it is now $_POST['ParentDiaryID'] as suggested and it now inserts no problem at all.  Thank you

Comment: Do not forget to close/delete/answer your own question so it won't clutter the index :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic rookie mistake, fixed by removing $.